# Nested Lists Hover Issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am using nested lists in my page.
Example -

```
 - Parent1  
  - Child1
     - GrandChild1
     - Grandchild2
     - Grandchild3
  - Child2
     - Grandchild4
     - Grandchild5
```

I want to use `li:hover { color:blue; }` for each family member individually. However when I bring the mouse cursor to any of the family member, color of all family members changes to blue. How to avoid that? Kindly help.

Comment: And wheres the code? Also that `=` in your CSS makes it invalid.

Comment: There really is no good way to do that in CSS, as hovering a child will also trigger the hover for the parents that match the same selector, unless you're only trying to target the "grandchildren"

Comment: You could try it with [Qjuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/sel_parent_child.asp)

Comment: @ Mr. Goose>> But how? Can you please elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i got my mistake. I need bit more R and D but i made some of this js It is not perfect as you can see in  my fiddle but works once

```
$(function(){
$('li').hover(function(){

    $(this).css({'color':'#00f'});
    $(this).parents().css({'color':'#000'});
    $(this).children().css({'color':'#000'});
},function(){
    $(this).css({'color':'#000'});
});
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepak_datwani/9pGXF/)

Comment: This is okay. Only fault is that it leaves the blue color at each immediate parent. Any way to avoid it? If yes, then I'll be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Try simply giving the ul a class and hooking into that, for example:

```
ul.mylist li:hover {color:blue;}
```

You can then also do

```
ul.mylist li ul li:hover {color:blue;}
```

You can also use the nth child/first-child/last-child.

```
ul li:first-child:hover {color:blue;}
```

The possibilities are endless, but by simply doing

```
li:hover {color:blue;}
```

You are referencing every li regardless of the markup previous to it.

Comment: Actually I am making a structured folder view of my server files. So in fact there can be many levels. So I have to hook into the last possible level in my CSS? (say 50th level). Something easier than this?

Answer (score 0):

Some usefull information here [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp)

```
ul:nth-child(2)
{
background:#ff0000;
}
ul:nth-child(3n)
{
background:#990099;
}

li:nth-child(4)
{
background:#00FF00;
}
```

A [jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/s4F4E/)

The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.

n can be a number, a keyword, or a formula.